# Regex Match base64 string and remove non-matching text/charcters

Tags: c#, regex, encoding, base64

I have a *valid* Base 64 encoded string - `someBase64String` to which an *invalid suffix* (e.g. `_002_CWLP265MB136330847F70EDE0813A5AC4C3A80CWLP265MB1363GBRP_--`) has been added.

I want to *split* the string back to *valid* Base 64 encoded prefix and *invalid* suffix.

This Matches a base 64 encoded string

```
Regex rg = new Regex("^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$");
```

`rg.Match(someBase64String)`  will return true if it is a valid base 64 string

When added to the `someBase64String` this string --`_002_CWLP265MB136330847F70EDE0813A5AC4C3A80CWLP265MB1363GBRP_--` is added at the end of the `base64encoded string` which causes the conversion of the whole 
 base64 string to fail. the `rg.Match(someBase64String)` will also return false.

In the case of an invalid base64 string(as described above), I need to extract the part/characters of the string that causes the conversion to fail; namely `_002_CWLP265MB136330847F70EDE0813A5AC4C3A80CWLP265MB1363GBRP_--` in this case.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and supply strings that should work and strings that should fail? Also, most likely, just removing the `$` from your regexp will return you the longest match of a (somewhat) valid Base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not filter out the characters with a help of *Linq*? If you want to *take* base 64 symbols up to invalid suffix use `Take` instead of `Skip`

```
 string wrongSince = string.Concat(source
   .SkipWhile(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ||
                   c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ||
                   c >= '0' && c <= '9' ||
                   c == '+' ||
                   c == '/'));
```

**Test:**

```
string valid = "ABC+DEF+123";
string suffix = "_002_CWLP265MB136330847F70EDE0813A5AC4C3A80CWLP265MB1363GBRP_--";

string source = valid + suffix;

string wrongSince = string.Concat(source
   .SkipWhile(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ||
                   c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ||
                   c >= '0' && c <= '9' ||
                   c == '+' ||
                   c == '/'));

 string correctPrefix = string.Concat(source
   .TakeWhile(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ||
                   c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ||
                   c >= '0' && c <= '9' ||
                   c == '+' ||
                   c == '/'));

Console.WriteLine(wrongSince);
Console.WriteLine(correctPrefix);
```

**Outcome:**

```
_002_CWLP265MB136330847F70EDE0813A5AC4C3A80CWLP265MB1363GBRP_--
ABC+DEF+123
```